# Image in tableviewcell not appearing immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

When the tableview appears, at first there are no images. But when I drag it, the images in the tableviewcells will appear. I am using a custom tableviewcell class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UserCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UserCell  alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
     NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    [cell setUser:_chatContent[indexPath.row]];
    [cell initUI];
    return cell;
}
```

This is my custom cell class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
}
-(BOOL)initUI{
    BOOL isSuccess;
    self.userImageView =  self.user.userImageView;
    UIView *superView = self.contentView;
    [superView addSubview:self.userImageView];
    [self.userImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(superView.mas_top).with.mas_offset(8);
        make.bottom.equalTo(superView.mas_bottom).with.mas_offset(-8);
        make.left.equalTo(superView.mas_left).with.mas_offset(8);
        make.width.equalTo(superView.mas_height).with.mas_offset(-16);
    }];
    self.userImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.userImageView.frame.size.width/2;
    self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    isSuccess = YES;
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Finally, this is my imageview code:

```
User *user = _chatContent[i];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"jpg"];
user.userImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:filePath]];
```

Comment: you should NEVER prefix a method that isn't an initializer with `init`.

Comment: thanks your suggestion.i will correct it.But it can't solve my question

Comment: that is why I didnt post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set the cell's `imageView.image` to `nil` before setting image for imageView because tableView reloads cells every time it is scrolled.
After setting `imageView.image` call `setNeedsDisplay` and `reloadInputViews` of UITableViewCell to set image immediately.

```
[cell reloadInputViews];                
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am sorry that i didn't write it clear. the initialization of imageview is in the viewdidload. the imageview has instance,before the tableview appear.But i still thanks for your help